# Accessing a property from an object in same script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script that searches the map for a bunch of objects, sorts them according to distance and selects the closest one as the target, assigning the closest one as "SelectedTarget"

I need to get the "mass" property attatched to "SelectedTarget" so I can let the AI decide if it will chase "SelectedTarget" or run away. I have been at this for hours, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Here's my code:

```
public class PredatorScript : MonoBehaviour {

public float mass = 1;
public float size = 1;

public List<Transform> FoodTargets;
public Transform SelectedTarget;
private Transform myTransform;
Transform target;
public float speed = 1;
public float sight = 1;
private float distance = 0;
private int counter = 0;

void Start () {

FoodTargets = new List<Transform>();
SelectedTarget = null;
myTransform = transform;

AddAllFood ();

}

public void AddAllFood()
{

GameObject[] Foods = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Herbivore");

foreach (GameObject enemy in Foods)
   AddTarget (enemy.transform);

}

public void AddTarget(Transform enemy)
{
FoodTargets.Add (enemy);
}


private void SortTargetsByDistance()
{
    FoodTargets.Sort (delegate(Transform t1, Transform t2) { 
       return Vector3.Distance(t1.position, myTransform.position)
          .CompareTo(Vector3.Distance(t2.position, myTransform.position));
    });
}

private void TargetEnemy()
{
if (SelectedTarget == null) {
   SortTargetsByDistance ();
   SelectedTarget = FoodTargets [0];
} 
else {
   SortTargetsByDistance ();
   SelectedTarget = FoodTargets [0];
}
}

void Update(){

TargetEnemy ();


distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, SelectedTarget.transform.position);

mass = SelectedTarget.trasform.mass; <------- This is what i've been trying

if (distance < sight) 

{
   transform.LookAt (transform.position + 
        new Vector3 (0, 0, 1), 
        transform.position - SelectedTarget.transform.position); //Face target
   transform.Translate (Vector3.down * speed * Time.deltaTime); //movement forwards

}

else {

   if (counter >= 120){
     transform.Rotate(0, 0, Random.Range(0, 360));
     counter = 0;
   }

   transform.Translate (Vector3.down * (speed/3) * Time.deltaTime);
   counter++;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [GetComponent](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html) method

So you would have something like this:

```
mass = SelectedTarget.GetComponent<NameOfScriptThatHasMassProperty>().mass;
```

Comment: Ok, I think I can use this. But if I may ask, what if the mass property is inside the same script? Is there a way around that? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean.

The Transforms you are storing in the list of Targets doesn't contain the script that has the mass data.

The beauty of components and game objects that Unity uses is that a GameObject is essentially a empty bag where you can put tons of different components. A transform is one of these components, it stores positional and rotational data (among other things.) GameObjects can also have your custom scripts. The GetComponent allows you to cherry pick a single component off of the object.
You may want to read about using FindObjectsOfType<MyComponent>()